# Instead maintain session

Tags: soapui, session-cookies

I'm working with SoapUI 5.3.0 and trying to pass through test case's option:'Maintain HTTP session'. When I use it with rest request can go between test steps, but when trying to pass phpsessid (I think that it is needed to pass only) something crashes and receive "Session expired". This happens thru post request. I added needed headers in my post request and pass the phpsessid and it is correct. When I compare the headers from the post request (working example - this one with 'Maintain HTTP session') with this one from the second attempt (without 'Maintain HTTP Session') they are the same. With the sames headers. Here they are:

[post login raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oOaQ.png)

[post login raw without maintain session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e7ZD.png)

Do you have any idea what is going wrong and why in second case I can't go through and receive 'Session expired'?

Comment: Do you want to maintain the session or you want a different way to handle it?

Comment: Yes, I want a different way to handle it. Because, when I use maintain session all is OK. But want to see the other ways. I have tried to pass csrf[login] in post request and tried to pass it as a Post QueryString but without success.